# Sending data between Java to c++ on windows?

Tags: java, c++, pipe

I want to send the raw audio buffer to c++ for audio transcoding.
I have two option

1. using piped stream

   - using direct buffers (java.nio)

Are these really my 2 best options (and which would people recommend?) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct buffers in NIO will almost certainly have better performance.  This is pretty much the ideal case for direct buffers.

I'm not sure what the point of your question is - if you want to know if there are other options, then the answer is certainly yet (you could, for example, write to a file then invoke an external application to process it - or you could use JNI without direct buffers).  But if you want a tightly coupled, highly performant interface between Java and C++ code, JNI along with direct buffers, is going to be the tool to use.

Comment: i am using JNI along with direct buffers

Answer (score 3):

[JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is easy to screw up, therefore people tend to complain about it. But it is an excellent and extremely stable option, when done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use sockets (that accepts connection from local) but that will be more effective on *nix systems I guess.

Comment: raw audio buffer will be created while recording from browser.
does browser supports creating local sockets?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need realtime transcoding, I would choose the buffers approach. In this way you have better control and you'll be sure that no byte is lost.